# Circular gradients in .NET WinForms app

Tags: .net, winforms, gdi+, gradient

In my WinForms app (C#) I have a circle (defined by a `Rectangle`) that I am presently filling with a solid color. I would like to fill this with a *circular* (not linear) gradient (so one color in the center fades to another color uniformly around the edges).

I have experimented with `PathGradientBrush`, but am having no luck (I still see a solid color). If anyone has any sample code that does this, that would be terrific!

Comment: @Ali - no, it's WinForms, not WPF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/Gradiator.aspx?msg=2732284).

```
private void label1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
    gp.AddEllipse(label1.ClientRectangle);

    PathGradientBrush pgb = new PathGradientBrush(gp);

    pgb.CenterPoint = new PointF(label1.ClientRectangle.Width / 2, 
                                 label1.ClientRectangle.Height / 2);
    pgb.CenterColor = Color.White;
    pgb.SurroundingColors = new Color[] { Color.Red };

    e.Graphics.FillPath(pgb, gp);

    pgb.Dispose();
    gp.Dispose();
}
```